# How to know the size of .cab file content without expanding it using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cab

For example, I have file demo.cab.
I want to know size of all files(extracted!) inside demo.cab. I don't want to extract files from it.

How can I do this using Windows PowerShell?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the cabarc.exe tool. Use the `l` parameter to list the content of the cabinet file.
As it  outputs some unwated text we have skip the first 9 lines. Then we replace "more than one space" to a space and so create a csv file. Finaly we call `measure-content` to get the sum of the files size :

```
cabarc.exe l .\hpchl118.cab > c:\temp\cab.txt
((gc C:\temp\cab.txt |skip -First 9) -replace '\s+',' ' | `
convertfrom-csv -delimiter " " -Header "file","size","date" | `
measure -property size -Sum | select  -expand sum)/1MB
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But do you know how to do this using only native Windows tools?

Comment: cabarc is part of the windows xp resource kit, i'm not aware of other built in tool